# One UI element for all VC

Tags: swift, uiview, viewcontroller

How I can create Custom view element with animation like a separate class for all view controllers, so that not write this element each time for each VC.
For example:
I am want create bottom view with button and if I am press on button animation will be appeared, and I am can do different action for different VC.

How I can create this view with animation one time for all VC and implement different action inside VC?

I can only create it each time for each VC, all work done but it's terrible code and sometimes may be hard for maintenance.

This it example how I am create my bottom menu and this way looking good but how work.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class BottomMenu: UIViewController {
      
    static let shared = BottomMenu()

    var yPosBottomUIView: CGFloat = 90.0
    var yPosCenterButton: CGFloat = 35
    var yPosBackButton: CGFloat = 35
    var yPosForwardButton: CGFloat = 35
    var yPosContextMenu: CGFloat = 35
    var yPosUpdateButton: CGFloat = 35
    var backButtonEnable: Bool = false
    var forwardButtonEnable: Bool = false
    
    lazy var image: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - yPosBottomUIView, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 90))
        if (osTheme == .dark) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                image.image = UIImage(named: "SurfaceBlack")
            }
            return image
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                image.image = UIImage(named: "SurfaceLight")
            }
            return image
        }
    }()
    
    lazy var centerButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX / 2) - 25, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50) - yPosCenterButton, width: 50, height: 50))
        
        if (osTheme == .dark) {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1)
        }
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Menu"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centralButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isEnabled = false
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var backButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.minX) + 25, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 15.5) - yPosBackButton, width: 36, height: 36))
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "whiteBackArrow"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centralButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isEnabled = backButtonEnable
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var forwardButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.minX) + 90, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 15.5) - yPosForwardButton, width: 36, height: 36))
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "whiteBackArrow"), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centralButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isEnabled = forwardButtonEnable
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var contextMenu: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX) - 60, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 15.5) - yPosContextMenu, width: 36, height: 36))
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ContextMenu"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(contextMenuButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var updateButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX) - 125, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 15.5) - yPosUpdateButton, width: 36, height: 36))
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "updateN"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centralButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isEnabled = false
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var blur: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        blurEffectView.effect = blurEffect
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0
        
        return blurEffectView
    }()
    
    @objc func centralButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        print("Center Tapped")
    }
    
    @objc func contextMenuButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        print("Context Menu Tapped")
// IF I am past blur effect here and some action for diffent VC nothing happens but each time I'll saw printed text above)
    }

}
```

This is image of menu which I am create but I am write code each time for each VC[image: BottomMenu]

Menu have ... when I press on it I am show the same animation for all VC and add some others view BUT When I am closed others sub view I am want implement different action depend of VC where menu did be opened.

Comment: You're missing some *very* key details in your question. For instance, you state you are able to do it, but only for each individual VC. Are you using a storyboard, a XIB, or doing this all in code? A specific answer to your vague question is hard... so I'll answer my way, in code. (Keep in mind, there's nothing in a storyboard you cannot do in code.) Subclass `UIView` with `UIButtons`, actions, and finally animation. At that point, simply instantiate this UIView subclass in each of your VCs....

Comment: Now if you need to (and you probably do), add delegation to this subclassed view - this creates a 1:1 link between *each* instance of this UIView subclass and the *specific* VC view that instantiated it. Most of this is something you can find good tutorials on. When you have something almost working except for a *specific* issue, come back and give us code that we can duplicate the issue - most of us would be glad to help.

Comment: This is example how I am create menu, and it don't work https://gist.github.com/IhorYachmenov/17b4f427b71f2aba11e1fdc962dc188a and I am did create this menu just duplicate code for all VC(, terrible way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried making one controller as base controller that can be inherited by all child controller and the common actions/activites to be part of that controller. Or maybe using a container view for child controller so that you can inherit properties of your base controller to your child controller.It depends on whatever suits your actual requirements
[image: Maybe something like this you can use]

Comment: I am just create 3 separate VC and create separate class "BottomMenu" where I am create view like "lazy var centerButton: UIButton = {}()" and then use access to it BottomMenu.shared.centreButton, but when I am press on button nothing happens but I am past animation with blur effect inside "addTarget method", my full code of menu https://gist.github.com/IhorYachmenov/17b4f427b71f2aba11e1fdc962dc188a